# URL Rewriting Issue - IIS7

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Hi I have a html website which just has some static content. the website is hosted on iis 7 and its named as www.mywebsite.com. Everything works fine. its just that when I type in mywebsite.com it was not redirecting to www.mywebsite.com so I setup the url rewrite rule for it in IIS and that works fine. but when I type in http://mywebsite.com, it does not redirect to http://www.mywebsite.com even if I have the redirect rule in place. I also tried using http redirect module and even that does not help. could somebody please help.

The rule that i have setup is in IIS directly so cant paste the code here. 
I am using the exact match pattern and specified the input url directly as

http://mywebsite.com redirect to http://www.mywebsite.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an answer, I created another site with the name mywebsite.com and pointed to the same directory and redirected to the actual site.